# jQuery Event Methods: How to change javascript 'click' event to 'always-fire'

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html, methods

I have this simple JavaScript in my footer that triggers a div with a footer in it to open or close when clicked.  How can I always show this element (in this case `footer-widget`) by default?

You can [see it in action here](http://bestfitmobile.com/) at the bottom.

Below is my JavaScript. I thought I needed to change the `'click'` event to some other jquery event method, but that doesn't solve the problem.

```
$(".open-footer").live('click', function(){
    $("a.open-footer").removeClass('open-footer');
    $(this).addClass("close-footer");
    $('.footer-widget').slideDown(500);

    var elementClicked = ("#footer");
    var destination = $(elementClicked).offset().top;
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination-0}, 1500, 'easeOutExpo' );    
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly, you want the footer-widget div to stay open by default.

You can do this two ways:

1. Find the CSS file that is declaring how footer-widget should be rendered. There, you need to set it to display the div by default. Usually CSS like 'display: inline' or 'visibility: visible' is enough.
2. Explicitly set it in your script file on window load - you'd probably set it just like you would for CSS, but using JQuery syntax (eg. $('.footer-widget').css('display', 'inline').

If you can, please post your CSS file, maybe we can help a bit more if we know the default styles being applied!

**EDIT:** Taking a look at your website on Chrome's inspector view, your style.css contains:

```
.footer-widget {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    display: none;
}
```

If you change **display: none** to **display: inline**, then footer-widget will always be visible.

Enjoy!

Comment: solved! First option worked fine. I didn't know the construction existed that you can set a div on display:none in the css, but let Javascript overrule and control this, so I never checked css for this. My shortcoming... Thank you very much!!